# Is it possible to have two cores in one GPU?

Tags: graphics-card

Instead of plugging two graphics cards containing one core each rather can a graphic card have two cores.

Comment: Sure; it's possible just not a huge market for them.  The cooling is the major problem.

Comment: and it costs a lot more and very noisy under load unless you get one that is already water cooled.

Comment: The benefit for a GPU is also much less than for a CPU. CPUs are serial, so more cores is a huge boost to performance. GPUs are parallel, so adding a core is not really much more, of any more effective than just adding shaders...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you define "Core" modern GPU's already have anywhere between dozens to thousands of cores on them already.

The thee main components you could count as "Cores" are the [Shader Processors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_shader_model), [Texture mapping units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_mapping_unit), and [Render output units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Render_output_unit) on the processor. Going with the current top of the line card (a Nivdia GeForce GTX 780 Ti) it has 2880 shader processors, 240 texture mapping units, and 48 render output units.

Comment: I think he is talking about a product with more than one GPU unit.

Comment: @Ramhound Ok, than go to a GTX 690. it has two discrete GK104-355-A2 chips on a single card.

Comment: Yeah,now I got its a GPU unit...I was talking.